# Error: Invalid Client - Sign In With Apple with Spring Boot

Tags: java, ios, authentication, jwt, sign-in-with-apple

I am receiving an `400 : [{"error":"invalid_client"}]` error when trying to exchange my authorization code for a refresh token. I tried everything and double-checked many times.
I am using [this](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) libary for generating the client secret. Below I used a sample key for demonstrating the issue.
What could be wrong?

**Apple Client Secret Generator**

```
public class AppleClientSecretGenerator {

    private String team_id;
    private String sub;
    private String key_id;
    private long expiration_time;
    private String secret_key;
    private String aud;


    public AppleClientSecretGenerator() {
        super();
        this.team_id = "***********";
        this.sub = "com.example.app";
        this.key_id = "**********";
        this.expiration_time = 200000;
        this.secret_key = "MIGTAFKMN23SFF2SFGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHdfDSFFDe09hGVEu5sesMNNF" +
                "pet8GJDZIL0inL4oxgIJNF0i3Q8MYKOgsdCgYIKoZIzj0DAQehRANCAAQhAVyKVrFGWEw+" +
                "gkWyeQNxopjG30iF56DXM0QfqwbffKmsdPkjfe3FKDDFyDYmk+XZM4qj6aIZKLy" +
                "KLM4Nd23";
        this.aud = "https://appleid.apple.com";
    }

    public String generate() {
        String jws = "";
        try {
            byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secret_key);
            //byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename));
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
            PrivateKey key = keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes));
            SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.ES256;
            long nowSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Date now = new Date(nowSeconds);
            long expMillis = nowSeconds + expiration_time;
            Date exp = new Date(expMillis);

            jws = Jwts.builder()
                    .setHeaderParam("kid", key_id)
                    .setIssuedAt(now)
                    .setSubject(sub)
                    .setIssuer(team_id)
                    .setAudience(aud)
                    .setExpiration(exp)
                    .signWith(key, signatureAlgorithm)
                    .compact();
        } catch (JwtException e) {
            //don't trust the JWT!
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Client Secret: " + jws);
        return jws;

    }
}
```

**Authorization Request**

```
public class AuthorizationRequest {

    private String client_id;
    private String client_secret;
    private String code;
    private String grant_type;
    private String redirect_uri;


    public AuthorizationRequest(String client_secret, String code) {
        super();
        this.client_id = "com.maxtrauboth.BopdropSwiftUI";
        this.client_secret = client_secret;
        this.code = code;
        this.grant_type = "authorization_code";
        this.redirect_uri = "http://mylocaladdr.test/";
    }

// Getters and Setters here
```

**Verify User**

```
@PostMapping("verify")
public UserCredentials verify(@RequestBody UserCredentials credentials) {

        Jwk jwk;
        Algorithm algorithm;

        // Validate identity token
        DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(credentials.getToken());
        JwkProvider provider = new UrlJwkProvider("https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys");

        try {
            jwk = provider.get(jwt.getKeyId());
            algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey(), null);
            algorithm.verify(jwt);

            // Check expiration
            if (jwt.getExpiresAt().before(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())) {
              throw new RuntimeException("Expired token!");
            }

            // Create client_secret
            AppleClientSecretGenerator generator = new AppleClientSecretGenerator();
            String client_secret = generator.generate();

            // Refreshing the token by sending the authorization code
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
            headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));
            headers.set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 Firefox/26.0");

            System.out.println("Authorization Code: " + credentials.getAuthorization_code());

            AuthorizationRequest request = new AuthorizationRequest(client_secret, credentials.getAuthorization_code());

            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(request.toString(), headers);

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            // send POST request
            TokenResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject("https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token", entity, TokenResponse.class);

            // do some database work here

        } catch (JwkException e) {
            // error
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // error
        }

        // sending the token back to the user 
        return credentials;
}
```

**Generated Client Secret**

```
{
  "kid": "*********",
  "alg": "ES256"
}
{
  "iss": "*********",
  "iat": 1587930164,
  "exp": 1587930364,
  "aud": "https://appleid.apple.com",
  "sub": "com.example.app"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the cause for the issue. However, I solved the problem by following the exact steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58252089/sign-in-with-apple-java-user-verification).

Answer (score 0):

The Issued at and Expiry time should be in seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: Good hint! However, I still get this error. I updated the code above.

Comment: would you mind showing your client secret string? try paste it in jwt.io , and see if the decoded client secret is correct

Comment: Wow, after pasting it in jwt.io it turns out ```iat``` and ```exp``` have the same value ```1587928```. How can this be?

Comment: Hmm i think no need to divide by 1000 for the now time, and try add *1000 for the exp time, ie, exp = now + 5*1000

Comment: Refer to https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/10/31/jwts-with-java

Comment: But that was what I had before. Shouldn't also be the ```iat``` value much bigger than ```1587928```? This number seems fairly small for seconds since Epoch, in UTC...

Comment: Oh ya it should have three more digits behind, I dont use Java myself so I am not sure how the date and jwt generation process in java

Comment: Okay, now after changing it back to the old version again, the seconds ```iat``` and ```exp``` look good. However, I still get the error. I updated the above example to show the generated client secret.

Comment: I think 4 seconds might be too short, try add 200 seconds (5 minutes) for the exp

Comment: No, still the error :/ BTW, it says ```invalid signature``` on jwt.io. So it might be something wrong with signing. I am checking it now..

Comment: Do you have the .p8 private key file? You can generate the public key for it using this command in terminal : "openssl ec -in AuthKey_123ABC456.p8 -pubout -out AuthKey_123ABC456_public.p8" , then you can open the public key file, copy paste its content into the jwt debugger to check signature

Comment: I created the public key and pasted it along with the private key in the debugger, but nothing changes. Does it automatically check the signature when the two keys are provided?

Comment: You only need to paste the public key in the debugger, and it will check the signature. I am not sure if your private key format is correct in the code, as the original file (.p8) has newline (\n) character after every 64 characters.

Comment: Okay, I pasted the public key with and without line breaks and ```-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----``` and ```-----END PUBLIC KEY-----```. Still it says invalid signature. My private key file is exactly how I received it from Apple. I haven't changed it.

Comment: Probably something wrong with the signature generation I guess, sorry cant help here as I am not good with Java

Comment: Are perhaps the line breaks necessary for the private key string inside the code?

Comment: could be, you can try adding line break after every 64 characters for your private key string