# How to create Sign in with apple user verification?

Tags: c#, webforms, jwt

I am trying to implement apple sign-in. C# version of this -> [Sign in with Apple Java User Verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58252089/sign-in-with-apple-java-user-verification)

Created JWT and don't know how and where to send request.

```
 public static string CreateNewToken()
    {
        const string iss = "isss";
        const string aud = "https://appleid.apple.com";
        const string privateKey = "key";

        CngKey cngKey = CngKey.Import(
          Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey),
          CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        JwtSecurityToken token = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: iss,
            audience: aud,
            subject: new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> { new Claim("CLIENT_ID", CLIENT_ID) }),
            expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
            issuedAt: DateTime.UtcNow,
            notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(
              new ECDsaSecurityKey(new ECDsaCng(cngKey)), SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256));

        return handler.WriteToken(token);
    }
```

Comment: have you looked at the [Official Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple)?.... Or [this tutorial](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/Implementing-Sign-In-with-Apple-in-ASPNET-Core)?

Comment: @GlynnHurrell Yes. I am generating token but I'm getting 'Invalid Client' error as a response