# Handling AppStoreConnect certificate

Tags: openssl, app-store-connect

I am trying to implement AppStoreConnect auth in my Java app and I cannot manage to parse the provided certificate correctly.

When signing JWTs for login, I am using following code:

```kotlin
fun parseApplePrivateKey(keyFile: String): PrivateKey {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58252089/sign-in-with-apple-java-user-verification
    val reader: Reader = InputStreamReader(AppleOAuth::class.java.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(keyFile)!!)
    val pemParser = PEMParser(reader)
    val converter = JcaPEMKeyConverter()
    val keyInfo: PrivateKeyInfo = pemParser.readObject() as PrivateKeyInfo
    return converter.getPrivateKey(keyInfo)
}
```

This works and also, I can openId login p8 with:

```
openssl ec -in apple-open-id-private-key.p8 -text
```

However this doesn't work for the appstoreconnect private key p8 and the `pemParser.readObject()` returns `null`.

I couldn't event manage to read the p8 file with openssl and I cannot even manage to find the format in which it is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The private key provided by Apple is unencrypted and must be preprocessed with `openssl` as follows:

```
# openssl pkcs8 -nocrypt -in AuthKey_123456789.p8 > apple-appstoreconnect-private-key.p8
```